# Why is this breaking Visual Studio's Intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, intellisense

Does anyone know why Visual Studio 2008's Intellisense is acting funny?

If I say `BEGIN_MSG_MAP`, I get this: [image]

If I say `BEGIN_MSG_MAP_FOO`, I get this: [image]

Either way, **the macros are all undefined**, so what's the deal?

[image]

And nope, I am not using *Force Include* anywhere, so this is the actual entire source file -- there's virtually nothing defined, as shown below:

[image]

Comment: are you sure they are all undefined?

Comment: @Daniel: See the new screenshot.

Comment: So, you're asking "Why does IntelliSense not work for this invalid code that I've written?"  For what it's worth, IntelliSense in Visual C++ 2010 does not give a completions list for either code sample.

Comment: @James: I think you missed the point. **Both** of them are invalid, because I haven't included anything. But Intellisense works for `BEGIN_MSG_MAP`, and *not* for `BEGIN_MSG_MAP_FOO`. Why would it do that?

Comment: That question can only be definitively answered by someone who knows how the Visual C++ 2008 IntelliSense engine works.  Any other answer is mere speculation.

Comment: @James: on the other hand, internals of some products are often more or less disclosed in public (I wouldn't be surprised to find some generic description of the improved inner workings of IntelliSense on some MS blog).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `END_MSG_MAP()` has a `}` which closes the scope of `CMyDialog`, hence `test()` will be in the global scope. Look at the drop down lists. It is precisely that.

Comment: No, it's an undefined macro. I don't have anything that `#include`s it.

Comment: Yeah I agree, I took it back right after. :) But it's definitely not the right answer.

Comment: are you sure you compiler settings isn't including atl?

Comment: It shouldn't be... it says `Not Using ATL`, and I don't see anything in `Force Includes` or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

*Notice: this answer is based entirely on speculation, if someone posts a good answer based on actual knowledge of how IntelliSense works I'll be glad to upvote it and delete mine.*

I suppose that IntelliSense has some special case to handle by default the most common MFC/ATL macros, or maybe it supposes that some default headers may be included to be able to handle the fact that your file, even if it doesn't include the MFC headers, could be included in a `.cpp` where such default headers are already included (which is often seen in headers, even if they should be including their dependencies).

But being `BEGIN_MSG_MAP_FOO` a completely unknown macro, it starts acting funny because it is actually an unknown identifier, probably interpreted as some unknown macro that could close the current scope. Thus, after it, it "plays it safe" and restarts parsing as it was the beginning of a new file, and thinks that `test` is a global function (as testified by the upper-left combobox), where `this` makes no sense.

Comment: That's definitely a possibility, but then I can't help but wonder: What's so special about `BEGIN_MSG_MAP` to make it worthy of this? It doesn't seem like it would need special support of any kind...

Comment: MFC projects are literally filled with it, training IntelliSense to know at least that they do not change the current scope can be a good idea.